# Server compile in one line for my html and js

Tags: javascript, html, server, cpanel

My HTML and js code works fine in local but when I put it into the live server, it compiles everything in one line, so if I do something comment then rest code gets commented. How do I fix it? Is there any way to prevent the code put into one line in live sever?